# How to skip a test case which has Theory attribute not Fact

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

How to skip a data driven test case for some reason?

I can skip a test case with Fact but getting an exception when using skip for parametrized test cases.
Exception: Xunit.SkipException: 'Exception of type 'Xunit.SkipException' was thrown.'

```
[Theory, OwnData(@"Data\own.json"), Category("Own")]
        public void Transfer(OwnDataTestConfig own)
        {
            bool? result = null;
            Skip.IfNot(own.FeatureConfig.SameCurrencyOnly);
result = Own.VerifyTransfer(_basicActions, WebDriver, own);;
            Assert.True(result.Value);
        }
```

Test case should be skipped if own.FeatureConfig.SameCurrencyOnly is false.

Comment: [Theory(Skip = "reason why do you skip")]

Answer (score 16):

xUnit does not process `SkipException` as such.

The way you do that is via a `Fact(Skip="Reason")`.

`[Theory]` also has a `Skip` property which works similarly.

Throwing from even one case in a Theory aborts the processing.

So I'd suggest you use an `if (bad) return;` to skip the processing.

Answer (score 3):

Skipping test cases (be it facts or cases from a theory) *dynamically*, based on a run-time choice, can be done by extending xUnit's features.

I recommend adapting [the DynamicSkipExample from xunit.samples](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/DynamicSkipExample) (licensed Apache 2.0, copyrighted by their respective authors), which includes this sample usage:

```
[SkippableTheory]
[InlineData(null)]
[InlineData("Hello, world!")]
public void DynamicallySkipped(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
        throw new SkipTestException("I don't like to run against null data.");

    Assert.StartsWith("foo", value);
}
```

So basically, in usage, you can dynamically throw a specific exception that leads to Skipped test cases instead of failed ones.

The code can be found in linked repository under its own license. It wires things together with an `IXunitTestCaseDiscoverer` but the interesting bit are in the `TestCase` (one for `Fact` and one for `Theory`):

```
public override async Task<RunSummary> RunAsync(IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink,
                                                IMessageBus messageBus,
                                                object[] constructorArguments,
                                                ExceptionAggregator aggregator,
                                                CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
    // Duplicated code from SkippableFactTestCase. I'm sure we could find a way to de-dup with some thought.
    var skipMessageBus = new SkippableFactMessageBus(messageBus);
    var result = await base.RunAsync(diagnosticMessageSink, skipMessageBus, constructorArguments, aggregator, cancellationTokenSource);
    if (skipMessageBus.DynamicallySkippedTestCount > 0)
    {
        result.Failed -= skipMessageBus.DynamicallySkippedTestCount;
        result.Skipped += skipMessageBus.DynamicallySkippedTestCount;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And its associated `IMessageBus`:

```
public bool QueueMessage(IMessageSinkMessage message)
{
    var testFailed = message as ITestFailed;
    if (testFailed != null)
    {
        var exceptionType = testFailed.ExceptionTypes.FirstOrDefault();
        if (exceptionType == typeof(SkipTestException).FullName)
        {
            DynamicallySkippedTestCount++;
            return innerBus.QueueMessage(new TestSkipped(testFailed.Test, testFailed.Messages.FirstOrDefault()));
        }
    }

    // Nothing we care about, send it on its way
    return innerBus.QueueMessage(message);
}
```